# The C standard's word on the switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement, bit, standards, representation

Consider this code example:

```
char c = 0xff;
char mask = 0xfe;
switch ((unsigned)(c & mask)) {
case -2: /* do task 1 */ break;
default:   /* do task 2 */
}
```

Let us assume that CHAR_BIT = 8 and the implementation defined assignment to c and mask is via interpretation of the bit patterns: 11111111 and 11111110, and negative zeros are allowed. The behaviour of this code is therefore:

if char is signed and implementation uses 2's complement, `c = -1, mask = -2, c & mask = -2, (unsigned)(c & mask) = UINT_MAX - 1`.

if char is signed and implementation uses 1's complement, `c = 0, mask = -1, c & mask = 0, (unsigned)(c & mask) = 0`.
`c` is zero and not negative zero because C does not allow creation of negative zero via an assignment.

if char is signed and implementation uses signed magnitude, `c = -127, mask = -126, c & mask = -126, (unsigned)(c & mask) = UINT_MAX - 125`

if char is unsigned `c = 255, mask = 254, c & mask = 254, (unsigned)(c & mask) = 254`

The case constant `-2` is converted to the same type as the controlling expression, so the value is `UINT_MAX - 1`. Hence it would only match if char is signed and implementation uses 2's complement.

Is this correct according to the C standard or are there additional assumptions that needs to be added?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this correct according to the C standard

Not really. If `char` is signed and 8-bit (ie. `CHAR_MAX` is less than 255), then the line

```
char c = 0xff;
```

is implementation-defined. It might do what you say, but it might not.

The C standard 6.3.1.3:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-deﬁned or an implementation-deﬁned signal is raised.

Comment: I was under the impression that this is implementation defined behaviour rather than undefined behaviour

Comment: Why would 0xff be undefined? It would be -1 if char is signed.

Comment: @Jim I would say it is because 0xff overflow a signed char

Comment: 0xff is a hex value, not a signed/unsigned value. It can represent both signed/unsigned values depending on the type it's being assigned to. (How else would one assign -1 as a hex value?)

Comment: @JimBuck: Not true, 0xff is just the same as 255. There are no "hex values", in C, only numbers.